# Using ilike in rust sqlx with push bind

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I am trying to dynamically create a query with a where clause and now i have the problem that I want to use push_bind to add a value because it's user input.

But i have the following Problem. If I build my query with push_bind I don't get any values:

```
if let Some(test) = &param.test{
    query_builder.push(" AND \"Test\" ilike '%");
    query_builder.push_bind(test);
    query_builder.push("%'");
}
```

On the other side if I build my query with only push I get the expected values:

```
if let Some(test) = &param.test{
    query_builder.push(" AND \"Test\" ilike '%");
    query_builder.push(test);
    query_builder.push("%'");
}
```

Can someone explain to me what push_bind is doing internally or how i would normaly do this with sqlx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`push` just pushes the literal string you pass it to the query, so it is vulnerable to sql injection like stated in the documentation,
`push_bind` on the other hand pushes a query placeholder `?` to the query, (and binds a value to it, but that isn't relevant here) just like the [documentation](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/struct.QueryBuilder.html#method.push_bind) says

So your variant with `push_bind` ends up pushing `" AND \"Test\" ilike '%?%'"` to the query, which is just nonesense. Instead you can concatenate the 3 different strings:

```rust
if let Some(test) = &param.test {
    query_builder.push(" AND \"Test\" ilike concat('%', ");
    query_builder.push_bind(test);
    query_builder.push(", '%')");
}
```

---

Hint: You can check what SQL a `QueryBuilder` produces with the [`into_sql`](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/struct.QueryBuilder.html#method.into_sql) method.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the mistake. Thanks for the hint